# How to simulate scroll down on webpage and save the process into video

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, recording

I have tons of website to scroll it's index page from top to bottom.

And save the "Animated Content" or "Dynamic js/css effect" among the scrolling process as a video.

I know the tool phatomJS can capture a screenshot.

Is there any tool can simulate scroll and get save the whole process into video?

Comment: You should be able using the `scrollTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the page has no dynamic content loading after first scroll.

- You can take a single screenshot with PhantomJS. Then, in the programming language of your choice segment the screenshot (with overlapping) moving a few pixels down (or up) and save as a frame image.

***OR***

- Take a bunch of screenshots that would make up your video. You can do this by setting [`page.clipRect`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/clip-rect.html) before taking the screenshot with [`page.render`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html).

You end up with a lot of images that you need to fuse into a video. Consult google for a tool that can take a bunch of images and convert them to video.

If you have something like an infinite scroll page, you still need to load the complete page before you start taking screenshots. This is usually done in the following way: [How to scroll down with Phantomjs to load dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561582/how-to-scroll-down-with-phantomjs-to-load-dynamic-content)

Comment: No, it has dynamic effect let why I need a video not a snapshot

Comment: Then you need to load the complete page first. PhantomJS cannot create a video on its own. You need to create the necessary screenshots yourself and use them to create a video.