# phantomjs : Go till the end of dynamically loaded Facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-scraping, automation, phantomjs

I wrote a javascript which when used in browser such as chrome, keeps on scrolling such facebook pages in which more content is loaded as you scroll.

```js
                    i = 0;
                    minutes = 30;
                    counter = minutes * 60;
                    function repeatScroll() 
                    { 
                        console.log('scrolling');

                        if (i < counter) 
                        {
                            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                            i++;
                        } 

                        setTimeout(repeatScroll, 5000);

                    }

                    repeatScroll();
```

I wanted to do same using phantomjs, but I am unable to do so. I am doubting it has something to do with the delay, but I am unable to figure it out.

This is a snippet from my phantom js code :

```js
var url = "https://www.facebook.com/search/965993006761563/likers";

        page.open(url, function (status) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                page.evaluate(function () {
                    console.log('gooooooooooooooooo');
                });
                page.render("liker.png");

                page.evaluate(function() {
                    i = 0;
                    minutes = 30;
                    counter = minutes * 60;
                    function repeatScroll() 
                    { 
                        console.log('scrolling');

                        if (i < counter) 
                        {
                            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                            i++;
                        } 

                        setTimeout(repeatScroll, 5000);

                    }

                    repeatScroll();

                });
```

Console only outputs `scrolling` once. I am not sure what changes do I need to do.

After scrolling all the way through out I want to extract all profile id's too. Planning to add this just below the above code.

```js
                var title = page.evaluate(function() {
                    var e=document.getElementsByClassName("fsl fwb fcb");
                    var ids = [];
                    for(var i = 0 ; i < e.length; i++)
                    {
                      ids.push(JSON.parse(e[i].childNodes[0].getAttribute("data-gt")).engagement.eng_tid);
                    }
                    console.log(ids);

                    return ids;
                  });
```

Also, when I currently add it, I do not get any profile id output.

Edit : I already read this ([How to scroll down with Phantomjs to load dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561582/how-to-scroll-down-with-phantomjs-to-load-dynamic-content?rq=1)) but this is not present in my case.

Comment: why not use the graph api instead? you are not allowed to scrape on facebook anyway. also, getting page data with the graph api is a LOT easier than using phantomjs for this.

Comment: @l There is no way of getting list of people who have liked a page in Graph API. :(

Comment: @luschn There is no way of getting list of people who have liked a page in Graph API. :(

Comment: There is no way because there is no reason to actually get them.

Comment: @WizKid How can you say so? I want the list of all 'fans' to say, perform a giveaway, or maybe for some other such task, then?

Comment: Perform a giveaway is not allowed. You are not allowed to give users anything just because they liked your page. Not even the chance of winning.

Comment: @WizKid I was following these guideline http://www.shortstack.com/is-your-facebook-contest-legal-infographic/

Comment: That is not correct. Read Facebook policies and not some third party site

Comment: @WizKid Okay, thanks. :) But that was not the primary aim, aim was to accomplish scrolling.

Comment: Correct but I work at Facebook so I'm not going to help you to do something against our policies

Comment: @WizKid Oh I am sorry, but I don't mean to offend any of those policies. I just want to learn automation. It was just a part of a learning process. I wanted to learn how to scroll in any website where data is dynamically loaded. For example in an ecommerce site, where in future I can write a script that will fetch the cheapest price of a, say TV set. I used example of Facebook because it is extremely common. I am sorry if I came as offender. I just wanted to learn to accomplish this using phantomjs.